# egrep word search + next 1 line

Tags: grep, solaris

I want to search word line using egrep with next 1 line. I don't know the syntax for egrep on a Sun Solaris system.

Answer (score 4):

The feature of showing additional lines before or after a grep match isn't provided in the native Solaris egrep, you would need to use GNU grep for it.

Depending on which version of Solaris you are using, this might be found in /usr/sfw/bin (Solaris 10) or /usr/gnu/bin (Solaris 11) or you may need to install it if it's not already there.

Comment: Later versions of Solaris 11 also provide GNU grep as `/usr/bin/ggrep`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure `perl`, which is a very basic tool available in nearly every system.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $matched = 0;
while (<>)
{
    if (/PATTERN/) { #for example /.2.*3/
        print;
        $matched = 1;
    } elsif ($matched) {
        print;
        $matched = 0;
    }
}
```